# How to insert a value into MySQL table from a list/menu in Java?

Tags: java

How to insert a value into MySQL table from a list/menu in Java? I am getting a error...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''',,'','o1','','a1','','q1','')' at line 1

And my query is

```
s="insert into customer values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"',"+s5+",'"+s6+
  "','"+s7+"','"+s8+"',"+s9+",'"+s10+"',"+s11+",'"+s12+"','"+s13+"','"+s14+
  "','"+s15+"','"+s16+"','"+s18+"','"+s19+"')";
```

My lists here are s13, s15 and s18.

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Add a `System.out.println(s)` after the above command, so we can see what causes the error.

Comment: The same error and iam not getting any output also

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `'` at `s5`, `s9`, s`s11`

Change the query to:

```
s="insert into customer values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"','"+s5+"','"+s6+"','"+s7+"','"+s8+"','"+s9+"','"+s10+"','"+s11+"','"+s12+"','"+s13+"','"+s14+"','"+s15+"','"+s16+"','"+s18+"','"+s19+"')";
```

EDIT:

Since your SQL column is VARCHAR, you have to convert the values to Strings.

Can't be sure exactly how to do this, since I don't know the class of your objects, but assuming your lists are `java.util.List` you do something like this:

```
s13 = Arrays.toString(o1.toArray())
s15 = Arrays.toString(a1.toArray())
s18 = Arrays.toString(q1.toArray())
```

Comment: s5 is actually date type and s9 and s11 are numeric type

Comment: Yes but you can still quote it.

Comment: and this o1,a1,q1 are the values for my 3 lists.

Comment: What class are your lists? And what type is the sql column?

Comment: Class is a css style 34, and the type is varchar(50)

Comment: Right before you construct the query.

Comment: Again error --  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 186 in the jsp file: /Banking/acntconfirmation.jsp
Arrays cannot be resolved
183:  Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/banking","root","hisrr");
184:  Statement st= conn.createStatement();
185: 
186:  s13 = Arrays.toString(o1.toArray())
187: s15 = Arrays.toString(a1.toArray())
188: s18 = Arrays.toString(q1.toArray())
189:

Comment: You have to import the Arrays class in your file. Add `import java.util.Arrays` right after the package declaration in the beginning of your file. Or if are using NetBeans, press `ctrl` - `shift` - `i`